# Entity Framework 6 + One-To One

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, one-to-one

my Entities are as follows:

```
public partial class Employee :Person, IEntity<long>
    {
.......
    public long Salutation_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Salutation_Id")]
    public  Salutation Salutation { get; set; }
}
public partial class Salutation:BaseEntity,IEntity<long>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string SalutationShort { get; set; }
        public string SalutationLong { get; set; }
        public string LetterSalutation { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to convert this mapping to FluentAPI.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything or did google for Fluent API?

Comment: Hi, yes, i did but i found only examples where both sides have a NavigationProperty, but i would like to have the Navigation only on the Employees side. reason, a couple of my entitys need salutation so i have no idead to handle that much navigationProps on the SalutationSide

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasRequired(e => e.Salutation).WithRequiredDependent().Map(ca => ca.MapKey(new string[] {"Salutation_Id"});
```

Of course, modelBuilder is an object of type DbModelBuilder, like what you would see when you override the OnModelCreating method of DbContext.

Comment: Hi, soory for the late answer, i will ttry that. Thanks Peter